# Intellisense will not show Attached Properties in C# Class Library

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, attached-properties

I wish to use attached properties in my application by making use of the code below (and taken from [here](https://www.csharpcodi.com/vs2/306/fasetto-word/Source/Fasetto.Word/AttachedProperties/BaseAttachedProperty.cs/#)). However, Intellisense in Visual Studio will not show the registered Attached Properties for some reason unknown to me. My application is an add-in and constrained to be a class library (.Net Framework 4.7.2)

Viewing the code below and taking cognizance of the definition for Attached Properties, I would think that the attached property would be defined as such

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Value", 
            typeof(Property), 
            **typeof(Parent)**, 
            new UIPropertyMetadata(
                default(Property),
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnValuePropertyChanged),
                new CoerceValueCallback(OnValuePropertyUpdated)
                ));
```

and NOT as such

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Value", 
            typeof(Property), 
            **typeof(BaseAttachedProperty<Parent, Property>)**, 
            new UIPropertyMetadata(
                default(Property),
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnValuePropertyChanged),
                new CoerceValueCallback(OnValuePropertyUpdated)
                ));
```

Notice the difference between `typeof(Parent)` and `typeof(BaseAttachedProperty<Parent, Property>)`. However, when I use this code in a Visual Studio Class Library, Intellisense does not show the defined Attached Properties that are defined for example:

```
 public class IsBusyProperty : BaseAttachedProperty<IsBusyProperty, bool>
    {
    }
```

Intellisense shows the cryptic information: `` local:BaseAttachedProperty`2.Value `` which I understand refers to the Base Class with two parameters. Is there some particular method to handle Generics and Base Classes with WPF so that Attached Properties are recognized as being in this Namespace and also being consumable? My goal is to ease the creation and consumption of Attached Properties in my application. I have done the cleaning, deletion of the `bin` folder to no avail. However, when I write an own AP for example:

```
public class IsBusyProperty
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Value", typeof(bool), typeof(IsBusyProperty), new PropertyMetadata(false));
        public static bool GetValue(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(ValueProperty);
        }
        public static void SetValue(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

the code compiles without the dreaded error that `the attached property is not found in the namespace local:...` or the `No implementation exception`!
Here is the reference code taken from [here](https://www.csharpcodi.com/vs2/306/fasetto-word/Source/Fasetto.Word/AttachedProperties/BaseAttachedProperty.cs/#).

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
 
namespace Fasetto.Word
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A base attached property to replace the vanilla WPF attached property
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="Parent">The parent class to be the attached property</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="Property">The type of this attached property</typeparam>
    public abstract class BaseAttachedProperty<Parent, Property>
        where Parent : new()
    {
        #region Public Events
 
        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when the value changes
        /// </summary>
        public event Action<DependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs> ValueChanged = (sender, e) => { };
 
        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when the value changes, even when the value is the same
        /// </summary>
        public event Action<DependencyObject, object> ValueUpdated = (sender, value) => { };
 
        #endregion
 
        #region Public Properties
 
        /// <summary>
        /// A singleton instance of our parent class
        /// </summary>
        public static Parent Instance { get; private set; } = new Parent();
 
        #endregion
 
        #region Attached Property Definitions
 
        /// <summary>
        /// The attached property for this class
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Value", 
            typeof(Property), 
            typeof(BaseAttachedProperty<Parent, Property>), 
            new UIPropertyMetadata(
                default(Property),
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnValuePropertyChanged),
                new CoerceValueCallback(OnValuePropertyUpdated)
                ));
 
        /// <summary>
        /// The callback event when the <see cref="ValueProperty"/> is changed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">The UI element that had it's property changed</param>
        /// <param name="e">The arguments for the event</param>
        private static void OnValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Call the parent function
            (Instance as BaseAttachedProperty<Parent, Property>)?.OnValueChanged(d, e);
 
            // Call event listeners
            (Instance as BaseAttachedProperty<Parent, Property>)?.ValueChanged(d, e);
        }
 
        /// <summary>
        /// The callback event when the <see cref="ValueProperty"/> is changed, even if it is the same value
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">The UI element that had it's property changed</param>
        /// <param name="e">The arguments for the event</param>
        private static object OnValuePropertyUpdated(DependencyObject d, object value)
        {
            // Call the parent function
            (Instance as BaseAttachedProperty<Parent, Property>)?.OnValueUpdated(d, value);
 
            // Call event listeners
            (Instance as BaseAttachedProperty<Parent, Property>)?.ValueUpdated(d, value);
 
            // Return the value
            return value;
        }
 
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the attached property
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">The element to get the property from</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Property GetValue(DependencyObject d) => (Property)d.GetValue(ValueProperty);
 
        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the attached property
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">The element to get the property from</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value to set the property to</param>
        public static void SetValue(DependencyObject d, Property value) => d.SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
 
        #endregion
 
        #region Event Methods
 
        /// <summary>
        /// The method that is called when any attached property of this type is changed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The UI element that this property was changed for</param>
        /// <param name="e">The arguments for this event</param>
        public virtual void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) { }
 
        /// <summary>
        /// The method that is called when any attached property of this type is changed, even if the value is the same
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The UI element that this property was changed for</param>
        /// <param name="e">The arguments for this event</param>
        public virtual void OnValueUpdated(DependencyObject sender, object value) { }
 
        #endregion
    }
}
```